# Misused word in "What topics can I ask about here?" section

Tags: word-usage

Not sure if should be here or meta, but as a word doubt I post it here.

In the section [What topics can I ask about here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
, there is a line about reposting questions on Stack Exchange sites.

> ...(but please do not post the same question on two difference Stack Exchange sites):

Is it a typo the use of word "difference" instead of "different"?

Comment: Indeed that is a typo. It has been fixed! Thanks both for letting us know, and for reading through the help :)

Comment: I think that whether you should post this on the main site or on meta depends on the reason why you're asking the question. If you're asking for the purpose of improving your own knowledge of English, then the main site is the best place to post it. If you're asking for the purpose of bringing people's attention to a potential problem so that they might fix it, then the meta site is the best place.

Comment: Actually, in my case, two reasons are valid. I asked because I was in doubt regarding the use of language, but I am also interested in fixing/helping/improving the platforms I use, in this case this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! It's a typo. It should be:

> please do not post the same question on two **different** Stack Exchange sites

Also, this question should be posted on Meta or in chat.

Comment: I don’t think it had to be posted in Meta if it wasn’t clear to the person asking  that it was a typo. We could make this useful to future visitors by explaining how we can detect that it is probably a mistake.